# BigQuery: UPPER case and NOT IN Cannot filter the result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, uppercase

My query is executed in the BigQuery, I am running a validation to verify the 'fieldID' only accept 3 values: 'Debit', 'Unknown', 'Credit'. Therefore, I executed the query to display every values, which is not 'Debit', 'Unknown' OR 'Credit', but the result surprised me. It shows 'Debit', 'Unknown' AND 'Credit'. My expectation is empty.

The query:

```
SELECT fieldId as outlier
FROM datasetId.tableId
WHERE UPPER(fieldId) NOT IN ('Debit', 'Unknown', 'Credit');
```

The result:

| outlier |
| --- |
| Debit |
| Unknown |
| Credit |

The result image is attached!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89b6Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use UPPER().

The moment you use UPPER(), with upper() it is trying to find ('DEBIT', 'UNKNOWN' ,'CREDIT'). which is different from   ('Debit', 'Unknown' ,'Credit').

Modified query:

```
SELECT fieldId as outlier
FROM datasetId.tableId
WHERE fieldId NOT IN ('Debit', 'Unknown', 'Credit');
```

Or you can try:

```
SELECT fieldId as outlier
FROM datasetId.tableId
WHERE UPPER(fieldId) NOT IN ('DEBIT', 'UNKNOWN', 'CREDIT');
```